# Running into TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable when calling update on ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedMap

Tags: ruamel.yaml

When I am trying to update my code to the new version of ruamel.yaml, I am running into issues.

code:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

print('Python', tuple(sys.version_info), ', ruamel.yaml', ruamel.yaml.version_info)

yaml_str = """\
number_to_name:
   1: name1
   2: name2
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print('before:', data)
data.update({4: 'name4'})
print('after: ', data)
print('==========')
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

## output with ruamel.yaml (0, 17, 4):

```
Python (3, 6, 13, 'final', 0) , ruamel.yaml (0, 17, 4)
before: ordereddict([('number_to_name', ordereddict([(1, 'name1'), (2, 'name2')]))])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/comments.py", line 779, in update
    self._ok.update(vals.keys())  # type: ignore
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/runamel.py", line 15, in <module>
    data.update({4: 'name4'})
  File "/home/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/comments.py", line 783, in update
    self._ok.add(x[0])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

The same code with the old version is working fine.

## output with ruamel.yaml (0, 16, 10)

```
Python (3, 6, 13, 'final', 0) , ruamel.yaml (0, 16, 10)
before: ordereddict([('number_to_name', ordereddict([(1, 'name1'), (2, 'name2')]))])
after:  ordereddict([('number_to_name', ordereddict([(1, 'name1'), (2, 'name2')])), (4, 'name4')])
==========
number_to_name:
  1: name1
  2: name2
4: name4
```

What I am doing wrong? (I Also suspect `vals.keys()` at line 779 is always going to raise Attribute error as `vals` is a tuple)

Comment: It is usefule to include the version of ruamel.yaml for each of these runs, or in case the Python version  is the problem, that version for both runs, in order to reproduce this. I recommend dropping IPython, unless you want to make other peoples life difficult. It is a PITA to extract a working Python program from these one-line snippets preceded by non-program irrelevancies, making it difficult to see if one gets the same input program as you did. (Maybe you can copy-paste that in IPython, but you can hardly expect someone to install that just to help you out).

Comment: I am using ruamel.yaml versions of 0.16.0 and 0.17.4 for each of these runs and I also updated the description with just working python and stdout output dropping ipython snippets. I apologize for this inconvenience and will never do that again. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: As you can see in my answer, I found the version in which this change. If the new version of ruamel.yaml solves the problem for you, please accept the answer so others will know it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue introduced between ruamel.yaml versions 0.6.12 and 0.6.13. It has been fixed
in version 0.17.9

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

print('Python', tuple(sys.version_info), ', ruamel.yaml', ruamel.yaml.version_info)

yaml_str = """\
number_to_name:
   1: name1
   2: name2
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print('before:', data)
data.update({4: 'name4'})
print('after: ', data)
print('==========')
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
Python (3, 9, 4, 'final', 0) , ruamel.yaml (0, 17, 9)
before: ordereddict([('number_to_name', ordereddict([(1, 'name1'), (2, 'name2')]))])
after:  ordereddict([('number_to_name', ordereddict([(1, 'name1'), (2, 'name2')])), (4, 'name4')])
==========
number_to_name:
  1: name1
  2: name2
4: name4
```